# Why are so many websites these days obsessed with having huge sticky sections at the top

Tags: website-design

For example this page

https://uk.indeed.com/viewjob?cmp=Hexagon-Recruitment&t=Refuse+Collector&jk=99dc36532252951a&q=bin+man&vjs=3

About a third of the screen is taken up by an incredibly irritating sticky section. I have already read that information and i know that i can simply scroll up to the top of the page should i decide to click on the 'Apply Now' button. But having that there the whole time just makes my blood boil and want to close the website down and never visit it again - how is this beneficial to either the user or the website owner. Is it a case that the marketing bods are overruling the UI/UX bods and insisting on this?

Even worse are the sites that have the page flying around all over the place if you dare scroll up a few pixels.

Comment: If this isn't just a [rant](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and you are really interested in an answer, please [improve the question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's beneficial because the scroll positions may get enormous and in testing sessions, Indeed may have observed that people often forgot which job they were applying to (people often apply to dozens of similar positions), or noted that scrolling all the way back up to read the title or apply took a significant effort, or users got lost.

In this case the main action is displayed at all times, thus their conversion rates would be predictable higher than one that was in a static position above or below the view port. This is unrelated to the visual design of how it was implemented or the decrease in enjoyment of using the app over time.